# Strange text in files

Tags: encoding, utf

I have some dump file which consist of string like

```
UserComment SeqOne A<E4 B8 80>B<E4 BA 8C>C<C3 96>D<F0 90 81 91>E
```

I am not able to understand what `<E4 B8 80>`, `<E4 BA 8C>`, `<C3 96>`, and `<F0 90 81 91>` mean in this string. Is it in UTF or some other encoding?

Comment: All I can see is hex. The rest seems arbitrary.

Comment: That can be anything... is you don't know what that is, what are you reading it for???

Answer (score 1):

This is just 3 hex-values. There isn't much one can tell about it, except for a few details.

A testrun to interpret the values to UTF16

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 0xE4B880,
            b = 0xE4BA8C ,
            c = 0xC396 ,
            d = 0xF0908191;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Character.toChars(a)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Character.toChars(b)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Character.toChars(c)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Character.toChars(d)));
    }
}
```

Only produces a `IllegalArgumentException`. So: No, these aren't UTF16-characters.

Most likely these are just a few IDs. Though that depends quite a lot upon the source from which these values are.

As @StephenC pointed out in the comments: they're no UTF8-characters as well.

Comment: They don't make much sense as UTF-8 either.